# Angularjs filter negated

Tags: angularjs

I have a set of items that I want to filter in ng-repeat using an ng-model as the string to filter the set, so far I haven't found a way to make it work when the expression is negated, I'm doing something like this:

```
<select ng-model="languageOrigin" ng-change="updatePrice()">
             <option ng-repeat="language in languages">{{language}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="languageDestination" ng-change="updatePrice()">
            <option ng-repeat="language in languages | filter:!languageOrigin">{{language}}</option>
</select>
```

In the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter), it says that we should use ! to negate the expression but still no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your filter is a method (not string or model) solution is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464809/reverse-polarity-of-an-angular-js-filter/17811582#17811582

Answer (score 43, accepted):

'!' character prepend to the filter string, like below:

> filter:'!'+languageOrigin

```
<select ng-model="languageOrigin" ng-change="updatePrice()">
  <option ng-repeat="language in languages">{{language}}</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="languageDestination" ng-change="updatePrice()">
  <option ng-repeat="language in languages | filter:'!'+languageOrigin">{{language}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That was the problem. the '!' needs to be a character. Thanks!

Comment: Use `ng-options` on select instead of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Is this still supported in v1.2.0rc1? I can't get this to work.

Comment: anyway to disable this?

Comment: Still supported in 1.2.14 @DavidRivers

Comment: Note: if the filter is a method, you need to do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/17811582/175830

Comment: in my case:
data-ng-options="Operation.Id as Operation.Name for Operation in allStepFromDb  | filter:({'StepId': !aWorkFlow.CurrentStepId})"> 
why it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 25):

If using objects, you might also be interested in the following:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="obj in objs | filter:({obj_attr: '!obj_val'})">
   ...
</li>
```

Tested in AngularJS 1.1.5.

Comment: it works when obj_attr contains string values but how should I specify not null? or not ''(empty) string?

Comment: that example did it for me, but beware that if you want to filter based on strings not empty, it will look awful but still work: `filter: {prop: '!' }` where '!' simply translates to 'not empty'. Ugly, but it works :)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: see ENDOH takanao's answer.

Looking at the AngularJS [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L95), <s>it appears that '!' negates the result of the predicate, not the predicate itself</s>:

```
var search = function(obj, text){
    if (text.charAt(0) === '!') {
       return !search(obj, text.substr(1));
    }
    switch (typeof obj) {
    ...
```

<s>So, one way to work around this is to</s> [If you don't like the '!'+myFilter syntax,] you can define your own predicate function in your controller:

```
$scope.inverseOriginFilter = function(item) {
    return item.search($scope.languageOrigin) == -1
}
```

Then use it in your HTML:

```
<select ng-model="languageDestination" ng-change="updatePrice()" 
    ng-options="language for language in languages | filter:inverseOriginFilter">
</select>
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/3eGGF/).

Comment: that works indeed, but I was wondering if it shouldn't be directly implemented by AngularJS...

Comment: this works fine if your model for each select drop down is the Destination itself, but what if its attached to something else already?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a method to filter than prefixing the method name with '!' will not work. Instead you can do something like:

```
// You can register this in your AppCtrl if you like, otherwise just use $scope.
$rootScope.not = function(func) {
    return function (item) { 
        return !func(item); 
    }
};
```

Then you do:

```
filter:not(myFilterMethod)
```

In your html it would look like:

```
<select ng-model="languageDestination" ng-change="updatePrice()">
  <option ng-repeat="language in languages | filter:not(languageOrigin)">{{language}}</option>
</select>
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17811582/175830

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 1.3.15 and [ENDOH's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450568/2406748) solution did not work. Instead, `filter:'!':languageOrigin` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To completely negate the $filter filter, i add this filter:

```
.filter('$nfilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function() {
        var itemsToExclude = $filter('filter').apply(null, arguments);
        return arguments[0].filter(x => !itemsToExclude.includes(x));
    }
}])
```

in template, we can write:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="type.id as type in data.types | $nfilter:{id: form.typeId}:true | filter: {label: $select.search}">
    <div ng-bind-html="type.label | highlight: $select.search"></div>
</ui-select-choices>
```