# Reverse polarity of an angular.js filter

Tags: angularjs

Given a filter method that returns true if some condition is met, is it possible to invoke its opposite in HTML, e.g. to use:

```
"item in items | filter:!AllDay"
```

instead of

```
"item in items | filter:AllDay"
```

? Or do you have to maintain two separate filter methods (one for false and one for true)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278371/angularjs-filter-negated/13279835

Comment: Thanks Mark - yep, the answer is there.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As noted by [ENDOH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278371/angularjs-filter-negated/13450568#13450568) (this SO question is technically a duplicate), you can negate a filter by prepending '!'  to the filter string, like this:

```
filter:'!'+myFilter
```

Note that the '!' is quoted. The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) is not terribly clear on this, and an example there would be helpful.

Comment: When myFilter is a method, not a model, this does not work on angular 1.0.7. The myFilter method is not called at all.

Comment: Good pointer about the '!' being quoted - that stumped me for a few minutes (and looks obvious in hindsight)

Comment: this was very helpful, for property based filtering instead of strings, it took a bit of trial & error though to figure out:  `filter:{myPropertyName:'!'+'EverythingOtherThanMe'}`

Comment: if the value for myFilter is '2', it will block 2, 22, 202, 102, etc.  I don't see how you can fix that without writing a function.

Comment: @shacker , check this fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33383/` , why last one is not display in list, event last one id is -12 not -1 ??

Answer (score 32):

shacker's answer didn't work for angular 1.0.7, so here's another way to do this:

```
// You can register this in your AppCtrl if you like, otherwise just use $scope.
$rootScope.not = function(func) {
    return function (item) { 
        return !func(item); 
    }
};
```

Then you would do this:

```
filter:not(myFilterMethod)
```

Comment: This is a proper answer for 1.2.9 version

Comment: This was the best answer for me in angular 1.3

Comment: Details on how to add to $rootScope at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880737/how-do-i-use-rootscope-in-angular-to-store-variables.

Comment: If you have lodash or underscore you can also do `$rootScope.not = _.negate;` with benefit being that it works if `func` has multiple arguments.

Answer (score 24):

```
filter:({day: '!'+AllDay.day})
```

Comment: I read on another SO post that this syntax also works:
filter:!{day:AllDay.day}
But it didn't for me. This was the only way that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a new negation filter and pipe it:

```
  .filter('not', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return !input;
    }
  })
```

```
"item in items | filter:AllDay | filter:not"
```