# How can i Apply filter by taking the arrays First value as Input On check?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Iam Learning AngularJs ...

Example : -

My Json Having  an array with some values as types  :-

Lets Say A Restaurant would be Mexican or Italian Etc 
 My example

```
 {
  name:'res 123',
  description:'Italian Rest'
   types:['Mexican','Indian']
   }

<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="Mexican"/> // Iam Using Textbox  Oncheck Filter Need to Filter all the Objects with types:['Mexican'] 

 Filter Code :- 
 <div class="col-xs-12" data-ng-repeat="obj in objs| filter : objs.types[1]: Mexican" > <!-- Filter applied Like this -->
 Realted looping 
</div>
```

How can i Apply filter by taking the types:['Mexican'] value as Input for Filter On check  ?

Comment: could you elaborate more what you want?

Comment: Hey Pankaj Please Take a Look i Just improved Question

Comment: @PRASAD, so, you have a list of restaurants (`objs` in your example) and you want to filter them by type?

Comment: Yes  It may Consists more than one value in array but i need to filter by first value or any value of array . But i Prefer to Go with First Value

Comment: What does it mean "by first value or any"? Doesn't that just reduce to "any value"?

Comment: If you're specifically wondering how to filter out results, perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464809/reverse-polarity-of-an-angular-js-filter

Comment: Sorry for the Confusion ..   i just need to filter by  one of the Value Specifically . If you have suggestion  on Filtering  Multiple values I can use that for efficient Filtering :-)

Comment: Just the built-in filter should work for the array just as it would if it was a primitive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Yes I did But the  Doc having Friends = [{obj},{obj}] But in My Scenario is types:['Mexican','Italian'] (types is embedded Field in Schema ).. where i stuck up

Comment: Are you unable to change the array to a better-suited JSON format, like this? `[{type:'Mexican'}, {type:'Indian'}];`

Comment: In the example, `friends` is equivalent to your `objs`, and `types` is one of the properties, like `name` in the "Friends" example

Comment: @Ed B Yes may be i need to raise request for Schema Change

Comment: @ New Dev let me Update My Model with some Fields

Comment: @ all  Could  you Please Give me an Idea How to Filter  By Mexican ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A built-in filter in Angular accepts a hash that specifies by what properties to match against each element in an array.

So, if you have an array of restaurants:

```
var restaurants = [
  { name: "foo", types: ["Mexican", "Indian"] },
  { name: "bar", types: ["Mexican"] },
  { name: "baz", types: ["Italian"] }
];
```

then if you need to filter by `name`, the input to `filter` would be `{name: 'b'}` - which would give you `"bar"` and `"baz"`.

Likewise, if you need to filter by `types` - even though it is an array - a similar approach would work: `{types: "Mexican"}`.

And so, you just need to construct that object - let's call it `filterBy`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterBy.types" 
       ng-true-value="'Mexican'"
       ng-false-value="undefined"> Mexican

<div ng-repeat="r in restaurants | filter: filterBy>
  {{r.name}}
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lyro4CVfi5mr8ucBF7yU?p=preview)**

Comment: @PRASAD, so did this address your question?