# how to create Custom filter angularjs javascript controller side?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

how to create Custom filter angularjs javascript controller side? 
i would like to search in array called segments by SegmentId, to create filter that do foreach on segments array search by SegmentId -

```
    //Controller

    $scope.GetSegmentDetails = function (id) {
        $scope.SegmentName = $filter('SegmentById')($scope.segments,id);
    }


    //Filter
    app.filter('SegmentById', function () {
        return function (input, searchPerson) {
        if (!searchPerson)
            return input;

        var results = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function (person) {
        }
    });

    return results;
}
```

});

Comment: please post an example model (i.e. `$scope.segments`)

Comment: I don't understand you want to create a filter to put logic in the controller? then you don't need a filter you can do it directly in the controller, filters are used to filter displayed data binded in HTML

Comment: @boindiil [{"SegmentId":"1","Description":"hod Registrations"},
{"SegmentId":"2","Description":"hod Inactive"},
{"SegmentId":"3","Description":"hod testUpd"},
{"SegmentId":"8","Description":"hod test"},
{"SegmentId":"1111","Description":"hod Release"},
{"SegmentId":"12","Description":"hod Requests"},
{"SegmentId":"13","Description":"hod Welcome Back"}]

Comment: @Charlie yes i know i can do it directly as private function, there is also a need to do it on the page it self, the same functionality...

Comment: oh ok well have you tried to import the filter object of your angular module in your controller? because I am not sure components in a module know about each others implicitly not sure how to do it but you should find smth with google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have to write your one filter to filter by `SegmentId`. Here you have an example

```js
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = [{"SegmentId":"1","Description":"hod Registrations"}, {"SegmentId":"2","Description":"hod Inactive"}, {"SegmentId":"3","Description":"hod testUpd"}, {"SegmentId":"8","Description":"hod test"}, {"SegmentId":"1111","Description":"hod Release"}, {"SegmentId":"12","Description":"hod Requests"}, {"SegmentId":"13","Description":"hod Welcome Back"}]
  
  $scope.filterData = function(segmentId) {
    return $filter('filter')($scope.data, { SegmentId: segmentId });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Full:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Segment in data">
      {{Segment.SegmentId}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  Filtered in View:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Segment in data | filter:{SegmentId:1111}">
      {{Segment.SegmentId}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  Filtered in Controller:
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Segment in filterData(1111)">
      {{Segment.SegmentId}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thanks! working great i have another issue with the order of loading module into controller. which mean $filter suppose to be second after $scope

Comment: Take a look a [this link](http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/)

Comment: @boindiil How to achieve `SegmentId !== segmentId` using $filter ?

Comment: @gauravbhavsar You could use the [negation within filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278371/angularjs-filter-negated)

Comment: @boindiil (+1) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Only need to add in your controller the filter dependency and then call it.

```
app.controller("YourController", ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter){

$filter('filterName')($args));

}]);
```