# Angularjs using ng-if for selective ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following arrays:

```
$scope.selected_items = [
    {id: "12345"},
    {id: "67890"}
]

$scope.list_items = [
    { id: "12345", name: "first", more: "data" },
    { id: "22222", name: "second", more: "data2" },
    { id: "33333", name: "third", more: "data3" },
]
```

I am trying to list out all the items in `$scope.list_items` who's `id` is not present in `$scope.selected_items`. I know I have to do something with `ng-if` but I can't figure out what to do.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in list_items" ng-if="????">
    {{ data.name }}
</div>
```

Could anyone help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest storing information if the object is selected within the array itself.

e.g.:

javascript

```
$scope.list_items = [
    { id: "12345", name: "first", more: "data", selected: true },
    { id: "22222", name: "second", more: "data2" },
    { id: "33333", name: "third", more: "data3" selected: true },
]
```

html

```
<div ng-repeat="data in list_items | filter:{selected:false}">
    {{ data.name }}
</div>
```

Comment: Or why not just `ng-repeat="data in list_items | filter:{selected: false}"` or use [negated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278371/angularjs-filter-negated) and avoid a ng-show

Comment: Thanks Roger. I modified my code to work with this. I appreciate the fast answer. What's more efficient @PSL? `ng-if`, `filter`, or `ng-show`

Comment: @bryan Most efficient would be to do the filtering in your controller (keep a filtered list and bind it to DOM and update the filtered list when you select an item)... so that expresion does not get evaluated every digest cycle. i.e `$scope.filtered = $scope.list_items.filter(function(itm){return !itm.selected})`. If you use filter on the DOM, ng-if, ng-show they all create a watcher.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you cant keep the selected state in the list_items array itself. you can probably call a function in the ng-if and check whether the item exists in the selected using a function.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in list_items" ng-if="checkItem(data)">
    {{ data.name }}
  </div>
```

The function will look like this,

```
$scope.checkItem = function(item)
  {
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.selected_items.length;i++)
    {
      var sItem = $scope.selected_items[i];
      if(sItem.id===item.id)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/3a4zoKIKFABAmif0fKFt?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the work around Kathir. I will definitely keep this in mind but it looks like the selected tag was more efficient so I modified my code.

Comment: I would agree thats the efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If it must be separated as in your example, you best bet is to create a new array with the items you want to ng-repeat.

So what you would do is something similar:

```
$scope.newList = [];
for (var i=0; $scope.list_items.length < i; i++) {
  for (var s=0; $scope.selected_items.length < s; s++) {
    if ($scope.selected_items[s].id == $scope.list_items[i].id) {
       $scope.newList.push($scope.list_items[i]);
    }
}
```

It would be ideal to do what the guy above me said, keep all of this in one object and just have a display: true/false flag in there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the correct pattern would be to use a AngularJS filter.

You just add the filter to your ngRepeat:

```
myApp.filter('selectedItems', function () {
    return function (values, selectedItemsArr) {
        console.log(values, selectedItemsArr)

        var arrayToReturn = [];
        // Loops through the values in the list
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            // Now loops through the selected items array to see if it matches
            for (var l = 0; l < selectedItemsArr.length; l++) {
                 if (values[i].id === selectedItemsArr[l].id) {
                    arrayToReturn.push(values[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
    };
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nitrium/3vcs445c/1/