# Hide non matching elements from array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters, gridstack

I have a search box with a ng-model assigned to it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchLibrary.text">
```

And a ng-repeat with a filter `searchLibrary.text`

```
<div ng-repeat="w in items | filter:searchLibrary.text" on-item-removed="onItemRemoved(item)">
```

So, when the user enters something, the filter removes all non-matching elements from the array, but is there a way to hide non-matching elements instead of removing them?

The reason why removing elements is problematic is I have a callback method assigned to the `ng-repeat` which gets called when a item is removed but it gets triggered when a user searches for some item which isn't the correct behaviour.

**Edit**: All the elements in the `items` array are draggable, so the user can manually drag and drop items from panel A to panel B. The callback is triggered when an item gets removed, but it shouldn't get triggered when user searches for a item description.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: may I know, how callbacks are getting fired when element gets removed from filtered collection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs filter negated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278371/angularjs-filter-negated)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-if` or `ng-show` to hide elements. You could replace

```
<div ng-repeat="w in items | filter:searchLibrary.text" on-item-removed="onItemRemoved(item)">
```

with

```
<div ng-repeat="w in items" ng-if="w === searchLibrary.text" on-item-removed="onItemRemoved(item)">
```

Here's a link to an example on CodePen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmPzMz

Comment: Not working. This hides all the items beforehand. Should be able to hide non-matching elements after the search term is entered

Comment: Try replacing ng-if with this: `ng-if="searchLibrary.text === '' || w === searchLibrary.text"`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an ng-class.

```
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

<div ng-repeat="w in items" ng-class="{'is-hidden': w===searchLibrary.text}"
    on item-removed="onItemRemoved(item)">
```