# ng-repeat filter - Not filtering right?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a filter in a ng-repeat to separate a list of Jsons in two sub-lists: One with Present-past items and other with future items. The json has a key called "dateFrom" which i compare with the actual date to determine in which list this item will appear.

But, despite the filter function only uses the "dateFrom" key to determine this, if i modify some other keys as well, the filter changes.

I made a quick jsFiddle to show the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/1j2p2hbg/1/

The filtering function is:

```js
$scope.isPast = function(item)
{
var now = new Date();
return (item.dateFrom <= now);
}
```

We have there 4 elements... 3 of them have the actual date and other has a future date.
The "isPast" function ONLY checks the "dateFrom" attribute, but if i change the attributes "keyBoolOne" and "keyBoolTwo", it will affect the filter as well.

Anyone could tell me why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Reversing the polarity of filters is problematic in AngularJS. It is also not mentioned in documentation but you should use

`<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter: '!'+keyBoolOne">`

instead of

`<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter: !keyBoolOne">`

But in your case, this still won't work because you are using function instead of attribute of objects.

## Alternative 1

To avoid this kind of unclear mistakes, you may define secondary filter function like follows;

```
$scope.isFuture = function(item){
    return !$scope.isPast(item);
}
```

and use it as filter for your second sub-list.

`<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter: isFuture">`

## **Alternative 2**

If you don't want to define additional function for each filter (which may negated), you can define "not" function on your own.

```
$scope.not = function(filterFunc) {
    return function (item) { 
        return !filterFunc(item); 
    }
};
```

And use it as follows (in anywhere / any sublist);

`<div ng-repeat="item in list | filter: not(isPast)">`

References to check;

[Reverse the polarity of AngularJS filters](http://akd.io/reverse-the-polarity-of-angularjs-filters)

[Negation on filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278371/angularjs-filter-negated/13450568#13450568)

Comment: Hi man, thanks for answering! In my actual project i have a similar problem, where some items does not appear in any of the 2 lists. The json is pretty the same but i cannot replicate it yet. Is there a way to pass only the "item.dateFrom" to the filter so it will completely ignore all the rest of the attributes? Thanks!