# show ng-repeat option values except for value in filter

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a `select` with `ng-repeat option`, How to show all the `options` except for the `options` which contains `'TM'`?

```
<select ng-model="mainCtrl.header.selectedItemId" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.items | filter:'TM'" ng-value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you try with `filter:'!TM'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in SO Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450568/4281154) you can use negation in your `filter`

```
<select ng-model="mainCtrl.header.selectedItemId" class="form-control">
        <option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.items | filter:'!TM'" ng-value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
```